React Native application stuck on Expo logo screen after building using eas
I'm facing an issue when building my react native application using eas. The application worked fine without any issue while running with expo normally, but now when building the application in the android emulator the app get's stuck in this screen. Screen image
In the Expo build dashboard the building process goes well without any error, so I'm really struggling trying to find the issue. I will put also the package.json if maybe there is some issues with the compatibility of the modules.
{
  "name": "app-name",
  "main": "expo-router/entry",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.3",
    "@googleapis/calendar": "^9.7.9",
    "@radix-ui/react-icons": "^1.3.0",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.1.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.23.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^13.1.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.2",
    "@supabase/supabase-js": "^2.44.3",
    "@tanstack/react-query": "^5.51.9",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.1",
    "expo": "~51.0.38",
    "expo-checkbox": "^3.0.0",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.2",
    "expo-crypto": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.7",
    "expo-image-picker": "~15.0.7",
    "expo-linear-gradient": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.23",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.2",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.6",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.7",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "js-levenshtein": "^1.1.6",
    "lodash.filter": "^4.6.0",
    "lucide-react": "^0.411.0",
    "metro": "^0.80.12",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-google-calendar-api": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.5",
    "react-native-element-dropdown": "^2.12.1",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.4.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-gifted-charts": "^1.4.16",
    "react-native-indicators": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.5",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-svg": "15.2.0",
    "react-native-url-polyfill": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "supabase": "^1.200.3",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.28"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@types/js-levenshtein": "^1.1.3",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.17.7",
    "@types/lodash.filter": "^4.6.9",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-native-calendars": "^1.1264.7",
    "@types/react-native-indicators": "^0.16.6",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.4",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.1307.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}

